# jQuery append function is making Cross Site Scripting Vulnerability

Tags: jquery, fortify

My fortify security scan throwing security errors in my code for using append() jQuery function. Because I used the data directly in append.

Here is my current code

```
function example() {
    $.get("example.cgi", { dummynumber: $('#dummynumber').text(), mode: 0  }, 
        function(data) { 
            $('#adminlistings').empty();
            $('#adminlistings').append(data);
        });
}
```

Now here my data variable contains HTML data. please suggest me how to get rid of this issue

Comment: [https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182989/jquery-get-html-code-and-xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182989/jquery-get-html-code-and-xss)

Comment: It's certainly a potential vulnerability, the actual risk depends on the provenance of the data returned by `example.cgi`. Better practice would be to have `example.cgi` return data (perhaps in JSON) that is expanded by the js code into the HTML required rather than blindly assuming that the HTML returned will be benign.